# Add a new remote repository <URL> for your repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to add a new remote repository  (public folders) to my repository.
Here are my steps in linux terminal:

1. $ git clone https: "MY OWN REPOSITORY"
2. $ cd folder
3. folder$ git clone https: "EXTERNAL PUBLIC REPOSITORY"
4. folder$ git init
5. folder$ git add --all
6. folder$ git commit -m 'First commit'
7. folder$ git remote add externalfolder https "EXTERNAL PUBLIC" REPOSITORY
8. folder$ git remote -v
9. folder$ git push origin master

What I'm doing incorrect since I can't open the remoted folder in my own repository in github?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to add a separate repository inside your own repo.

this concept is called as **submodule**.
you can add your external project as submodule
`git submodule add "EXTERNALPROJECTURL" "folder_path_where_you_want_to_clone"`

for more example and tutorials on submodule, you can refer to this [link](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html)